# Writing end of line to wxTextCtrl

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I was trying to write text to a `wxTextctrl` object in a `wxWidgets` application. Example code is below. For some reason, I'm not managing to get a line break. And most examples I've found online did one of the things that aren't working here.

[image: What I'm getting]

The code:

```
#include "wx/wx.h"

using namespace std;

class MainWindow : public wxFrame {
 public:
  MainWindow(const wxString& title);
  wxTextCtrl* textctrl;
};

class MyApp : public wxApp {
 public:
  virtual bool OnInit();
  MainWindow* main_window;
};

MainWindow::MainWindow(const wxString& title)
    : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, title, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(280, 180)) {
  // Add text window:
  textctrl =
      new wxTextCtrl(this, -1, wxT(""), wxPoint(-1, -1), wxSize(250, 150));

  // This writes to the middle of the text white space, but does not understand
  // endl \n or \r\n
  ostream log_stream(textctrl);
  log_stream << "Hey Joe! \n";
  log_stream << "Buckle up!\r\n";
  log_stream << "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" << endl;

  wxStreamToTextRedirector redirect(textctrl);
  cout << "Not yet " << endl;
  cout << "One more \n";
  cout << "Just one more \r\n";

  cout << "Fine, I quit.";

  Centre();
}
```

Also, the text is not breaking automatically due to the window size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create `wxTextCtrl` with `wxTE_MULTILINE` style. You then normally only need `\n` which will be correctly interpreted for each platform.